# Error 1004 on range.paste

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently getting mad on a macro.

I spent hours on the internet searching for a solution, but I came to the point where I have to ask for help :(

I get a

> run-time error '1004' application-defined or object-defined error

on this line: `Range(rngZelle1.Offset(1, 2)).Paste`

```
Option Explicit

Sub import()
Dim bk As Workbook
Dim sh, asheet As Worksheet
Dim rngZelle, rngZelle1 As Range
Dim strSuchwort, sDate, sPath, sName As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set sh = ActiveSheet
strSuchwort = "test"

sPath = "C:\Users\stefan.******\Downloads\" 'you dont need to know my real name :P
sName = Dir(sPath & "*.xl*")
Do While sName <> ""
Set bk = Workbooks.Open(sPath & sName)

For Each asheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
asheet.Activate
    For Each rngZelle In Range("A:A")
                If UCase(rngZelle) Like UCase(strSuchwort) Then

                sDate = Right(rngZelle, 10)
                Range(rngZelle.Offset(2, 1), rngZelle.Offset(25, 1)).copy

                For Each rngZelle1 In sh.Range("A:A")
                If rngZelle1 = sDate Then

                Range(rngZelle1.Offset(1, 2)).Paste '<---- thats the line i get the error

                End If
               Next rngZelle1
            End If
    Next rngZelle
Next asheet
```

Everything goes well up to the mentioned line. I tried to replace it for test purposes by "msgbox sdate" what went well.

What I really dont get, in the previous loop the copy goes well. It seems to be all about the paste line.

I hope one of you guys can help a totally noob out :) Every help is really appreciate as I'm getting really nuts on this.

Comment: Remove the Range(): rngZelle1.Offset(1, 2).Paste

Comment: other than Scott' comment be informed there no such method as `Paste` in `Range` class: use `rngZelle1.Offset(1, 2).PasteSpecial`

Answer (score 0):

`Paste` is a Workbook method which can't be used on a `Range` object.

The corresponding `Range` method is `PasteSpecial` which takes 4 optional parameters.  The *Paste* parameter takes an [xlPasteType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837425.aspx) which is `xlPasteAll` by default.  For clarity I usually include xlPasteType even if using the default.

If you change:

`Range(rngZelle1.Offset(1, 2)).Paste`

to:

`Range(rngZelle1.Offset(1, 2)).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll`

your code should work.

Answer (score 0):

Following the comments above by @Scott Craner and @user3598756 , there a few "corrections" need to be made:

`Dim sh, asheet As Worksheet` means `asheet As Worksheet` and `sh As Variant`.

The same goes to `Dim rngZelle , rngZelle1 As Range`, only the second one is `Range` while , `rngZelle As Variant`.

To conclude the first section of declaration, it should be:

```
Dim bk As Workbook
Dim sh As Worksheet, asheet As Worksheet
Dim rngZelle As Range, rngZelle1 As Range
Dim strSuchwort As String, sDate As String, sPath As String, sName As String
```

Regarding the `For Each asheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets` loop:

1. There is no need to `asheet.Activate` , you can use `With asheet` instead.
2. Regarding your error, if you **Copy >> Paste** in 2 code lines, you need to replace the syntax of the `Paste` line to `PasteSpecial xlPasteAll.

***For Each asheet* Loop Code**

```
For Each asheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    With asheet
        For Each rngZelle In .Range("A:A")
            If UCase(rngZelle.Value) Like UCase(strSuchwort) Then

                sDate = Right(rngZelle.Value, 10)
                Range(rngZelle.Offset(2, 1), rngZelle.Offset(25, 1)).Copy

                For Each rngZelle1 In sh.Range("A:A")
                    If rngZelle1.Value = sDate Then
                        rngZelle1.Offset(1, 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
                    End If
                Next rngZelle1
            End If
        Next rngZelle
    End With
Next asheet
```

Comment: Better men than me have given you answers, but this reference may help you with code in the future: http://www.excelitems.com/2010/12/optimize-vba-code-for-faster-macros.html

Comment: @SolarMike  I think you meant to put this as comment to the question , not my answer, right ?

Comment: yes its a comment for the OP and others, but not you sorry - my comment was badly placed.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for my late reply. Unfortunately I haven't had much time the last couple of weeks.

First of all, `.PasteSpecial` did the job :) thanks a lot!

> `Dim sh, asheet As Worksheet` means `asheet As Worksheet` and `sh As
>   Variant`

Thank you very much for the tip, I learned something new :)

Unfortunately the `with asheet` and `end with` results in a macro what doesn't copy and paste the figures, so I stick to the loop.

I managed to build a final and working macro, but it takes 90 Minutes to run (final version shall import 5 times of current data) and it blocks the clipboard while running.

So if anyone ha any idea how to speed it up and bypass the clipboard (copy destination etc doesn't work for any reason) it would be really appreciate.

```
Option Explicit

Sub import()
Dim bk As Workbook
Dim sh As Worksheet, asheet As Worksheet
Dim sSkill As Range, pval As Range, lstZelle As Range, target As Range, stype As Range, lstZelle1 As Range
Dim strSuchwort As String, sDate As String, sPath As String, sName As String, strSuchwort1 As String, strSuchwort2 As String
Dim row As Integer, col As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set sh = ActiveSheet
sPath = "C:\Users\*******\test\" 
sName = Dir(sPath & "*.xl*")

Do While sName <> ""
Set bk = Workbooks.Open(sPath & sName)

sh.Range("A1").AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
For Each lstZelle In sh.Range("B:B")
If lstZelle <> "" Then
strSuchwort = lstZelle & "*"
strSuchwort2 = lstZelle.Offset(0, -1)

    For Each lstZelle1 In sh.Range("C:C")
    If lstZelle1 <> "" Then
    strSuchwort1 = lstZelle1

        For Each asheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        asheet.Activate
        If asheet.Name = strSuchwort2 Then

            For Each sSkill In Range("A:A")
            If UCase(sSkill) Like UCase(strSuchwort) Then
            sDate = Right(sSkill, 10)

                For Each stype In Range(sSkill.Offset(1, 0), sSkill.Offset(1, 100))
                If UCase(stype) Like UCase(strSuchwort1) Then
                Range(stype.Offset(1, 0), stype.End(xlDown)).copy

                    For Each pval In sh.Range("1:1")
                    If pval = sDate Then
                    col = pval.Column
                    row = lstZelle.row
                    sh.Cells(row, col).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

                    End If
                    Next pval
                End If
                Next stype
            End If
            Next sSkill
        End If
        Next asheet
    End If
    Next lstZelle1
End If
Next lstZelle

bk.Close SaveChanges:=False
sName = Dir()

Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
sh.AutoFilterMode = False

End Sub
```